# Updating building data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, update

I need to update a building data (shapes) in ArcGIS Desktop.

One Shape is with the buildings of a city from 2012 and the otherone with the buildings of the same city from the year 2019 (perhaps 300.000 buildings). I need to update the shape from 2012 while changing the use of some buildings and while removing buildings, which doesn't exist anymore and add those which are new. I need to keep the 2012 shape because it has attached much more information than the 2019 shape.
The problem is, that there is no field in the attribute table to connect both shapes, there differences between the ID and all other fields. The second problem is, that the buildings are not exactly at the same place. Some yes but most of them are just a little bit beside (already checked: it's not a question of projection).

How can I update the 2012 shape without having to manually edit every single building?

Comment: It’s a little unclear what you are asking.  When you say “shape”, do you mean geometry?  Or attributes of each feature?  Please edit your question to clarify what it is you want to use from the 2012 data, and what you want to use from the 2019 data.

Comment: You have to come up with some way of defining a relationship between the features in the two datasets.  You say there are no attributes you can use and that they are not reliably in the same location, which rules out the two simplest methods.  Are they reliably near enough to always be the nearest feature from the other dataset?  If so, you can still use a spatial join.  Otherwise, you may have some manual work to do I order to define the relationships one by one (eg, by creating attributes and populating them with the same values).